# JavaScript check if array values exist in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

Hi I've an array and I've an array of objects

`const factArr = ['743156', '743157']`

```
[
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743156"
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743157",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743158",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743159",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743976",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "744961",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "746809"
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "747229"
    },
    {
        "adsId": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "747231"
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "749059"
    }
]
```

I want to check `factArr` values exists within this object, equal to(`adsFactId`). If yes I want to add two properties for that object `checked:true, checkBoxPatched: true`

so the O/P should be

```
[
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743156",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743157",
        "checked": true,
        "checkBoxPatched": true
    }
    //with the other objects
]
```

Anyways we can achieve it

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @0stone0 I don't think I forced you to answer the question, plz carry on with your work, don't give unwanted sermons, if you don't want to help others

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
const factArr = ['743156', '743157'];
const dataList = [
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743156"
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743157",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743158",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743159",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "743976",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "744961",
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "746809"
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "747229"
    },
    {
        "adsId": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "747231"
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "adsFactId": "749059"
    }
];

dataList.some(obj => {
  if(factArr.includes(obj['adsFactId'])) {
    obj.checked = true;
    obj.checkBoxPatched = true;
  }
});
console.log(dataList);
```

Comment: This does not provide the same output as OP is expecting. There shouldn't be false values added